# Unpack kwargs inside dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I can use `kwargs` when creating a dataclass object without issues:

```
@dataclass()
class Data:
    name: str =         'Unnamed'
    additional: int =   None
    things: int =       None

dic = {'additional': 123, 'things': 456}
res = Data(name='Somename', **dic)
```

---

```
Output: Data(name='Somename', additional=123, things=456)
```

However, I'd like to unpack the `kwargs` inside the data class when they're not part of calling arguments:

```
@dataclass()
class Data:
    name: str =         'Unnamed'
    additional: int =   None
    things: int =       None

    def __post_init__(self):
        self(**dic) #unpack kwargs to fields

dic = {'additional': 123, 'things': 456}
res = Data(name='Somename')
```

Comment: Why do you care if the unpacking is done inside the class or outside?

Comment: How do you propose to supply `dic` to your `__post_init__` thats being called by `__init__` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace Because the class will be called a large number of times and it's specified in a scripting language typed by the user.

Comment: @PatrickArtner in the production it will be called from another class.

Comment: shouldnt you then declare them dataclass.InitVar's as described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables ?

Answer (score 8):

A `dataclass` may explicitly define an `__init__()` method.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-level-decorators-classes-and-functions) states:

> The parameters to `dataclass()` are:
>
> `init`: If true (the default), a `__init__()` method will be generated.
>
> **If the class already defines `__init__()`, this parameter is ignored.**

Hence, you may define a standard `__init__()` method to process `kwargs`.

```py
@dataclass()
class Data:
    name: str
    additional: int
    things: int

    def __init__(self, name: str = 'Unnamed', additional: int = None, things: int = None, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up with a slightly different solution which achieves the intended goal:

```
dic = {'Somename': 123}

@dataclass()
class Data:
    name: str =         'Unnamed'
    additional: int =   None
    things: int =       None
    arg: int =          None

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.arg = dic.get(self.name, None)

res = Data(name='Somename')
```

---

```
Data(name='Somename', additional=None, things=None, arg=123)
```